# Remove Parts of String in php

Tags: php, html

is there any way to do this in PHP?

```
$first_string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$second_strong = "GHIJKLM";
function str_slayer($first_string, $second_string ){
  //doing some stuff
  return $data// return "ABCDEFNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
}
```

it means I want a PHP function with two string parameters. 2nd parameter is a part of 1st parameter. the function will cut the 2nd string part from the 1st string and the rest of the 1st string will return.

thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `str_replace()` to replace "He" for "". The code would look like this:

```php
$string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$substring = "GHIJKLM";
$final_string = str_replace($substring, "", $string);
echo $final_string;
```

The output would be:

```
ABCDEFNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

The `str_replace()` function will replace a substring, in your case "GHIJKLM", for an other string, in this case we will use "" because we want to remove it from the `$string`.

Comment: this is what I just looking for. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the str_replace function to remove an unnecessary string from the given string. and trim and preg_replace functions remove unnecessary spaces, tabs from the string.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1); 
    
    $str1 = "Mahbub Rashid Tonoy";
    $str2 = "Rashid";
    
    function strReplace(string $str1, string $str2): string{
        return trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',  str_replace($str2, '', $str1)));
    }
    
    print(strReplace($str1, $str2));
```